# How to connect an android application with a c# desktop application?

Tags: android, c#-4.0, networking

So heres the thing.. I am trying to make an order management/order-taking application using android and a remote desktop application that would receive the orders and send it to a terminal at the kitchen so the cooks and chefs will be able to process the orders for a single table..

It would go something like this..

Each table would have android tablets fixed on to them that would have the menus so that it would function much like any menu book for the customers, then as they browse they could kind of 'send to cart' the orders. Once they have finished picking their orders, theycould click a button which would then send it to a remote desktop server, which would keel a copy of the orders for receipt processing, then display the orders to a terminal screen on the kitchen.

The probelm here is, how do I actually send the orders to the remote desktop application and how will it receive it?

Comment: What about AJAX-enabled WCF service and JSON as a data format for messages? So Android/any client publish JSON message to a specified HTTP URL (WCF service)

Comment: what exactly is a wcf service? will i need to host a website of sorts?